# Collation Error in MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to delete the records of table by comparing it with a Date as in:

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE  DATE_ADD('MTN_CPCreateDate', INTERVAL 3 DAY) < CURDATE()
```

For this query, I am facing the following error

```
1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<'
```

I went through various posts but am not able to find the solution. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the column type of 'MTN_CPCreateDate'?

Comment: Coulmn data type is 'Date'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are columns/tables within your query that have different collations, being illegal for some operations.

Try changing the table/columns involved to a single collation

When you create the column of the table ask you for the collation. Here there is a collation mis-match

Comment: This works.. because I created a table with default collation in Date field, now when I run this query, it works fine. So change your collation.

Comment: The data type for my date column is Date ( eg 2013-06-27) and when I browse my table it dont show any collation for this column while for other columns, in the table it is showing as latin1_swedish_ci collation –

Comment: Look do from starting when you create the database leave it default. By default it is just written `Collation` don't change it. It doesn't make any difference. Then create a table and be sure tht collation field is remained unchanged. And try it now.

Comment: I didnt do anything with the collation property...by default the structure is like that.